# Separar String com .Split - C#

Tags: c#, string

Bom dia pessoal,

Estou tentando pegar uma parte especifica de uma string no Visual Studio, no caso a string em questão é um caminho de diretório: "C:\Users\Usuario\Arquivo-2018.txt" eu gostaria de tenta pegar só o que vem depois da ultima "\", tentei fazer

```
string[] texto = caminho.Split("\");
string resultado = texto[3];
```

Porém o código da erro, dizendo que não pode converter caractere para string, alguém poderia me ajudar nessa situação por favo? Desde já agradeço. 
obs: a variável "caminho" é do tipo string

Comment: Wesley, sua lógica está certa, porém troca `Split("\");` para `Split('\');`. Ou seja troca aspas duplo para simples.

Comment: Olá Matheus, obrigado pela resposta, acabou que eu consegui resolver com uma solução ali de baixo. Agradeço novamente sua resposta.

Comment: Você precisa entender porque o seu código não funciona.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tente utilizar o método `Substring`, ficaria assim:

```
string resultado = caminho.Substring(caminho.LastIndexOf(@"\") + 1);
```

Explicação: o método `Substring` tem a função de nos retornar algum "pedaço" da nossa string original. A forma que estamos utilizando nos exige o índice de início da nossa nova string, para isso, usamos o método `LastIndexOf` para dizer que queremos o índice da última `\` na sua string + 1 para pegarmos a partir do próximo caractere após a última `\`.

Comment: Olá Pedro, muito obrigado, deu certo aqui. Só vou esperar passar o tempo para marcar sua resposta como solução. Muito obrigado novamente.

Comment: Por nada, eu que agradeço!

Comment: Vocês que começaram agora e estão respondendo várias coisas, em coisas simples assim, é provável que já tenha várias duplicatas que mostra como fazer a questão. è melhor fechá-las.

Answer (score 3):

`.Split()` não aceita aspas duplas, somente aspas simples, ex:

```
string caminho = @"C:\Users\Usuario\Arquivo-2018.txt";
string[] texto = caminho.Split('\\');
string resultado = texto[3]; //Arquivo-2018.txt
```

*Fonte*: [`.Split()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/b873y76a(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: Em coisas simples assim, é provável que já tenha várias duplicatas que mostra como fazer a questão. è melhor fechá-las.

Comment: @Maniero sim é melhor fechar.